# Problem setting values in loop

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I've got som problem setting some values in my js-code. I've tried to figure out what the problem is but still can't find the issue in the code.

It's the mostN, mostE, mostW, mostS values I want to set.

The alert at the end of the code i "Undefined". Why? And How do I fix it?
Thx!

```
var mostN,
mostE,
mostW,
mostS;

for (i = 1; i < opts.markers.length; i += 1) //loops 5 times
{
$geocoder.geocode(
{
    address: opts.markers[i].address},
    function (result, status)
    {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
        {
            var str = [result[0].geometry.location]; // "(42.456465, -48.74116)"
            var realString = str.toString();
            var stop = realString.length - 1;
            var real = realString.substring(1,stop); // "42.456465, -48.74116"

            var arr = real.split(", ");

            var lat = arr[0].toString(); // "42.456465"
            var lng = arr[1].toString(); // "-48.74116"

            if(mostN > lat) { mostN = lat; }
            if(mostE < lng) { mostE = lng; }
            if(mostW > lng) { mostW = lng; }
            if(mostS < lat) { mostS = lat; }

            alert(mostN); // returns "Undefined"
        }
        else
        {
            if (opts.log) {console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); }
        }
    }
);
```

}

Comment: Do you ever actually set mostN to anything at all? It's not clear from this code that you do, which would explain why it's undefined.

Comment: @Awais well, not only in php variable can have name '$geocoder'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to be taking into account the sign of the lat and long. For example,

```
> var mostN, 
> ...
> var lat = arr[0].toString(); // "42.456465"
```

From your post, lat is already a string so converting it to string seems pointless. Given that later an arithmetic comparison is performed, it would be better to convert it to number up front:

```
var lat = Number(arr[0]); // 42.456465
```

or

```
var lat = +(arr[0]); // 42.456465
```

.

```
>  ...
>     if(mostN > lat) { mostN = lat; }
>     if(mostE < lng) { mostE = lng; }
>     if(mostW > lng) { mostW = lng; }
>     if(mostS < lat) { mostS = lat; }
```

The variable `mostN` has not been initialised so in the comparison it is equivalent to zero, which is **not** greater than 42.456465, so the test returns false and mostN is not set. However, `mostS` will be set.

But the sign of the comparison is wrong - if the latitude is a bigger +ve number it is more northerly so:

```
    if (mostN < lat) { mostN = lat; }
```

is what you want, same for the rest of the tests. However, you also have to take into account the hemisphere where -10 is more northerly than -20, so (provided mostN and lat are numbers, not strings):

```
    if ((mostN + 90) < (lat + 90)) { mostN = lat; }
```

since latitude is never greater than 90 degrees. For longitude, use 180. You can use any number you like that is 90 or greater for lat and 180 or greater for long, so you could use 180 for both but that might be confusing for maintainers.

Comment: Thanks alot! Realy great input!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
var SOMETHING_HUGE = 100000000;
var mostN = -SOMETHING_HUGE,
mostE = -SOMETHING_HUGE,
mostW = SOMETHING_HUGE,
mostS = SOMETHING_HUGE;

//...

if(lat > mostN) { mostN = lat; }
if(lng > mostE) { mostE = lng; }
if(lng < mostW) { mostW = lng; }
if(lat < mostS) { mostS = lat; }
```

Comment: I think you reversed some of the operands?

Comment: @Jeff - I'm using the +N, +E convention there :)

Answer (score 0):

Works as it should, since at the moment of check variable `mostN` is undefined, and condition `mostN > lat` is false.

Comment: It might "work" in that it produces the results the code defines, but it is logically wrong because not only are the comparisons backwards, but it doesn't allow for consider hemispheres.

Answer (score 0):

Your mostN is not clearly initialize with some value.Try to place alert inside

`if(mostN > lat) { mostN = lat; }`

condition. And also check the if comparison is correct or not.